# Grunt Compass Stack level too deep error

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compass

I'm running Grunt to compile some SCSS and whenever I include a border radius

```
@include border-radius(50%);
```

it throws this error

```
SystemStackError on line ["160"] of C: stack level too deep
```

I'm running npm@3.10.8 and grunt-contrib-compass@1.1.1

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Wondering the same, having the same issue ..